# Rails & mongoid - Get distinct values and their ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongoDB database with movie. Each document has a movie name, an ID, and tags. I want to display all the unique tag values in a dropdown list and to also be able to click on the tag and be able to show all the movies it is related to. 
 To do that I need the ID associated with the movie.

I'm able to display all the unique movies using this: `Movies.distinct(:Tags).each {|x| puts x }`

I've tried `Movies.distinct(:Tags).each {|x| puts x._id }`, this came up with an error.

Now how do I extract the ID value from `x`?

**EDIT**:
The document is structured like so

```
[ _id: Integer, movie: String, tags: Array ]
```

**UPDATE:**
Maybe a simpler question... if i have `Movies.any_of(:Tags => /comedy/i)` how can I get the value of `_id`? `Movies.any_of(:Tags => /comedy/i).only(:_id)` returns a document that I'm not able to get id from individually.. it just sets the other fields to nil.

Comment: Is tags an embedded document in Movies?

Comment: It's an array, so currently I go through each element of the array in all the documents but am only able to see the name of the movies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `.only(:id)` and saving that to a variable then going through it with `.each` and pushing it to an empty array